# Sliding Friction Force

Tags: friction, relative-motion

Sliding friction force is not dependent on velocity. Is wear dependent on velocity? For example, it takes 10 Newtons to overcome sliding friction, no matter if the relative velocity is 1m/s or 1000m/s. But does wear change if velocity is 1m/s or 1000m/s?

Comment: The question is ambiguous.  Are you going to slide an object over the same distance, on the same surface, but at two different speeds?  Does the object keep the same normal force on it in both situations?

Comment: yes to all of those.

Comment: What do you mean by "wear"? If it is a technical term, you might want to define it for others to understand.

Comment: I don't think wear is as amenable to a simple model as frictional force is. That said, a good first approximation is probably that wear increases with dissipated energy, e.g. the work done by friction. If so, then 10 times faster means 10 times more wear per unit time. But depending on material there may be considerable extra heating that causes friction parameters and material cohesion to change, as well.